# How to add new row in dataframe on specific condition

Tags: r

I have following dataframe in R,which is the output of some code in R

```
 Size total_weight
 20      1829000
```

Now, what I want is if there is only one row in above dataframe then I want to add other row as

```
 Size total_weight
 40        0
```

If only `Size` 20 is present then I want to add `Size =40 and total_weight =0` 
If only `Size` 40 is present then I want to add `Size =20 and total_weight =0`

Desired dataframe is

```
 Size total_weight
 20      1829000
 40         0
```

I have written following code in r

```
if(dim(weight)[1] == 1){
  if(weight$Size[1] == 20 & weight$total_weight[1] != 0){
    weight$Size[2] = 40
    weight$total_weight[2] = 0
   }else{
     weight$Size[2] = 20
     weight$total_weight[2] = 0
   }
}
```

But,it gives following error

```
 Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, Size, value = c(20, 40)) : 
 replacement has 2 rows, data has 1
```

Comment: The message is very clear.Have you tried `rbind`?

Comment: replace `weight$Size[2]` by `weight[2, 1]` and similarly for `weight$total_weight[2]` _->_ `weight[2,2]`, it'll works. But still looking for the reason behind ur error

Comment: `weight$Size[2]` for `condition dim(weight)[1] == 1` does not make sense (that is why you see `replacement has 2 rows, data has 1`), and you can use `nrow` and `rbind(weight,data.frame(Size=40,total_weight=0))`

Comment: @parth, replacement method `[<-.data.frame` can add new rows. but `$<-.data.frame` does allow that.

Comment: @mt1022, okay got your point but pondering.. is this behavior due to method of accessing dataframe (call by refererence etc. ) or something else ?

Comment: @parth, I am not sure whether I understand it correctly, but these are two different functions and both will make a new copy of data.frame (not change by reference like what data.table does).

Answer (score 1):

Using `%in%` removes the need to check dimensions and the nested `if` statement

```
df1 <- data.frame(Size = 20,  total_weight = 1829000)

if (!20 %in% df1$Size) df1 <- rbind(df1, list(20, 0))
if (!40 %in% df1$Size) df1 <- rbind(df1, list(40, 0))

  Size total_weight
1   20      1829000
2   40            0
```